# getting opposite value javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two strings: "a" and "b". How to get "b" from "a". And "a" from "b" without **if**? Like:

```
var arr = ["a", "b"];

function reverse(str){
    return arr[+!arr.indexOf(str)];
}
```

but in more elegant way.

Comment: What do you mean by "b" receiving "a" and "a" receiving "b"?

Comment: `return str == 'a' ? 'b' : 'a';` is more readable than what you have now. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: OP said without **ternary** or if else

Comment: @Gabe: It's an unnecessary constraint.

Comment: @Blender, that is example. Just want to know is there easier way..

Comment: @Blender do what ever you want, just stating what the OP asked for.

Comment: @SakerONE: If this is an example, what's your *actual* use case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many, many ways to do this.

```
var a = 'foo', b = 'bar',
    arr = [a, b];

// dictionary object
var o = {};
o[a] = b;
o[b] = a;

function reverse(x) {
    return o[x];
}

// equality with cast (+x or x|0)
function reverse(x) {
    return arr[+(x === a)];
}
// or
function reverse(x) {
    return arr[+(x === arr[0])];
}
```

If you just want to take turns between the two, you could write a generator

```
var reverse = (function () {
    var i = 1;
    return function () {
        return arr[i = 1 - i];
    }
}());
reverse(); // "foo"
reverse(); // "bar"
reverse(); // "foo"
```

Comment: I don't think this works. `['a','b'][true]` is `undefined`.

Comment: @Paul S. Question, in the generator code, i assume the anonimous function is stored in ´var reverse´, but where did the ´var i´ variable go?, how come it's not garbage collected?, looks like black magic to me...

Comment: @Ziul Welcome to using scope in _JavaScript_. Let me describe what is happening here. An _anonymous function expression_ is invoked, which creates "scope A" and returns another _anonymous function expression_, which is stored in variable `reverse`. "Scope A" is kept alive for as long as there exists a reference to a _function_ defined within "scope A", as the scope of this function (say "scope B") inherits "scope A", meaning that **as long as some "scope B" exists which is a child of "scope A", "scope A" won't be garbage collected.**

Comment: @Paul S. I see, i didn't know about that scope inheritance o.o, tnx for the cristal clear explanation =)

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
return arr[(str=='a')%2]
```

or if you don't want to hardcode 'a'

```
return arr[(str==arr[0])%2]
```

or (using the same idea)

```
return arr[+(str==arr[0])]
```

It looks marginally cleaner than your solution but how is it better than using the ternary operator ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [modulo operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

```
var arr = ["a", "b"];

function reverse(str){
    return arr[(arr.indexOf(str) + 1) % 2];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use char/ascii conversion:

```
function reverse(c) {
   return String.fromCharCode(195 - c.charCodeAt(0))
}
```

Try it

```
    alert(reverse('a'));
    alert(reverse('b'));
```

Comment: +1, this is a great example for exact strings `"a"` and `"b"`. Should really use `console.log`, though.